# How to access protected operator members in C++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, this, protected, derived-class

How to access protected operator members in C++

```
class A {
   char* m="ABCD";
  protected:
   const char& operator[](int i)const{ return m[i]; };
public:
A();
};

class B : Public A {
   char* D;
  Public:
B():A(){};
void display(){  ///////////what should I do here   }
};
```

If I have this code, and I want to use the operator [] inside the derived class, for example I need to display [0]=A inside the display from derived class. What's the solution here.

Comment: Please don't tag C++ questions as C.

Comment: Have you tried just using it? Does seem odd to do since this function is trivial and you could just do `m[i]` instead.

Comment: Is `display` supposed to be a member function of `B` or a free function? As written this is pretty unclear. If the latter, you just use `[]` directly. Maybe go with `(*this)[foo]` for more concise syntax than rewriting `operator[]`.

Comment: I tried, but this[i] == "A" doesn't work, and I'm sorry for the wrong tag

Comment: That's because `this` is a `B*` pointer, not a `B` object or a `B&` reference. You need to dereference it.

Comment: Needs to be `(*this)[i]`

Comment: No, @tadman is right - you should be able to directly access the member variable `m` in the derived class; that's what makes `protected` different from `private`.  No need to involve `this` at all.

Comment: @MarkRansom But `m` is private, not protected.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `protected` status, it's just non-obvious how you invoke `operator[]` in a clean way on `this`. I've duped to a question that covers that precise issue.

Comment: @NathanPierson you're right, my reading comprehension is a little off today.  Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

You can dereference this `this` object from within the member function and use the `[]` operator, i.e.:

```
void display(){  std::cout << (*this)[1];  }
```

Comment: but it doesn't work with `==` , what if      ` if((*this)[1]=="A");`, it got error

Comment: @Tim if you've tried it and it didn't work, copy that bit of code and the exact error message into the question.

Comment: @Tim That's because you're comparing a string to a character.  You want `'A'`, not `"A"`.

Comment: @Tim: `"A"` is a C-style string literal. The `operator[]` returns a reference to a `char`, not a C-style string. You wanted `if((*this)[1]=='A);` (single-quotes make it a `char` literal, not a C-style string literal).

Comment: @ShadowRanger now I'm really questioning my reading comprehension today, that's two trivial mistakes that just went over my head.

Comment: @MarkRansom: Volunteer to tutor the first year CS students at a local college. Best way I know of to develop a sixth-sense for the dumbest of errors. :-)